# How do you find the square of a multivariate binomial in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new to Python and would want to know if there is a way to square polynomial in python.

I have an array for example [7 5 1 1] which I want to square. The example is to be interpreted as `7x + 5y + z + 1`.

When I try to use polynomial functions of numpy, it gets interpreted as 7x<sup>3</sup> + 5x<sup>2</sup> + x<sup>2</sup> + 1 and gives me the output.

Please help me in this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: This site isn't a code writing service. What code have you already tried?

Comment: p1 = numpy.poly1d([7,5,1,1]) sum(numpy.square(p1)) -->76

Comment: @RolfofSaxony What do you mean exactly by "which I want to square ?" You want something like `7x^2 + 5y^2 + z^2 + 1` ?